# is the Sobolev space $H_0^1(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded 1D interval, a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I was wondering if the Sobolev space $H_0^1(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is bounded 1D interval while being associated with $L^2$ is Hilbert?

Comment: What do you mean by”while being associated”?

Comment: I mean the $L^p$ norm is $L^2$, integrability in the $L^2$ sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is Hilbert. The inner product can be taken to be
$$
\langle f,g\rangle = \int_\Omega f'g',
$$
or perhaps more naturally
$$
\langle f,g\rangle = \int_\Omega (fg+f'g') .
$$
These two inner products induce equivalent norms for $H^1_0$, as per Friedrichs' inequality.

Note however that the first one induces only a semi-norm for $H^1$.

Comment: Is this definition of inner product standard? why we do not add the inner products of the functions as well?

Comment: This is one of the standard ones. You don’t need to add because Friedrichs inequality says that the induced norm is a good norm.

Comment: @Sam, but/and, yes, $\sqrt{|f|^2_{L^2}+|f'|^2_{L^2}}$ is an equivalent (and more natural, from some viewpoints) norm on that Sobolev space.

Comment: @paulgarrett I think you mean ${\left\| f \right\|_{{L^2}}} + {\left\| {\partial f} \right\|_{{L^2}}}$
           Also, when dealing with Sobolev spaces, the derivative in question is the weak derivative?, coz our functions are allowed to be non-differentiable. Could you confirm these?

Comment: @Sam, first, no, to make a Hilbert space, it's the square root of the squares of the norms of $f$ and its derivative. Second, yes, the derivative has to be in some weak sense... or, define this with a classical derivative on test functions or $C^1$ functions, and take a completion with respect to this norm, dodging the immediate issue of "what kind of derivative", leaving it to be defined "by extending by continuity", etc.

Comment: @paulgarrett I do know what is extension by continuity, but I do not get the part where you speak about test functions and taking completion with respect to a norm, I thought completion by continuity is done via a limit.  what is completion w.r.t a norm. Could you plz elaborate or give a mathematical explanation?

Comment: @Sam, ah, I mean that a somewhat weak derivative (sometimes called "$L^2$-derivative") can be defined $H^1\to L^2$ by $g'=L^2-\lim f_n'$, where $f_n$ is a sequence of test functions that is Cauchy in the $H^1$ norm, approaching a general $H^1$ function $g$.